# Rails user to user messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, message

I'm very new to rails so please be detailed in your responses. I'm building a web app that uses devise for authentication. The part that I'm stuck on right now is a user to user messaging system. The idea is that User A logs into the app and can visit user B's profile, and on User B's profile can click on a link that allows User A to compose a message to User B. Then User B can log into the app and visit the inbox where User A's message will be found.

I believe that I'm having trouble defining the sender and recipient roles here, right now I'm trying to display the form that users will compose their message in. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here? I get the following error. I've read that the thing to do is add the User_id field to the table, but I'm hoping to link this messages up using sender_id and recipient_id, which both equal user_id (e.g. User 1[sender] sends a message to User 2 [recipient]):

unknown attribute: user_id

def new
  @message = current_user.messages.new recipient_id: params[:sender_id]
end

Additionally, for you rails experts or anyone that has done something similar to this, can you advise whether or not I'm going in the right direction, or offer any guidance? I'm sort of coding blind here and just trying to make it up as I go along. Any guidance would be hugely appreciated and save me a lot of time i'm sure. Code below:

Users Migration

```
class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table(:users) do |t|
      t.string :first_name
      t.string :last_name
      t.string :email,              null: false, default: ""
      t.string :encrypted_password, null: false, default: ""

      t.string   :reset_password_token
      t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

      t.datetime :remember_created_at

      t.integer  :sign_in_count, default: 0, null: false
      t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
      t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
      t.string   :current_sign_in_ip
      t.string   :last_sign_in_ip

      t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :users, :email,                unique: true
    add_index :users, :reset_password_token, unique: true

  end
end
```

Messages Migration

```
class CreateMessages < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :messages do |t|
      t.string :content
      t.integer :sender_id
      t.integer :recipient_id
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20140909174718) do

  create_table "messages", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "content"
    t.integer  "sender_id"
    t.integer  "recipient_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
    t.string   "email",                     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",        default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",             default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "current_industry"
    t.integer  "years_in_current_industry"
    t.string   "hobbies"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true

end
```

routes.rb

```
Catalyst::Application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations" }

  devise_scope :user do
    get 'register', to: 'devise/registrations#new'
    get 'login',    to: 'devise/sessions#new',     as: :login
    get 'logout',   to: 'devise/sessions#destroy', as: :logout
  end

  resources :users do
    member do
      get 'edit_profile'
    end
    resources :messages, only: [:new, :create]
  end

  resources :messages, only: [:index, :show, :destroy]

  root to: "home#index"
  match '/about',   to: 'static_pages#about',   via: 'get'
  match '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact', via: 'get' 
  match '/help',    to: 'static_pages#help',    via: 'get'
  match '/legal',   to: 'static_pages#legal',   via: 'get'

end
```

users_controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
    def index
      @users = User.all
    end

    def show
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    def new
    end

    def create
    end

    def edit
    end

    def update
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      @user.update!(user_params)
      redirect_to @user
    end

    def destroy
    end

    def edit_profile
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_industry, :years_in_current_industry, :hobbies)
    end

    def sender
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    def recipient
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

  end
```

messages_controller

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_recipient

  def new
    @message = Message.new
    @recipient = User.find(params[:user_id])
  end

  def create
    @message = Message.new message_params
    if @message.save
      flash[:success] = "Your message has been sent!"
      redirect_to user_messages_path
    else
      flash[:failure] = "Please try again."
      redirect_to users_path
    end
  end

  private

  def message_params
    params.require(:message).permit(:content, :sender_id, :recipient_id)
  end
end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :from_messages, class_name: 'Message', :foreign_key => "sender_id"
  has_many :to_messages, class_name: 'Message', :foreign_key => "recipient_id"

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :current_industry, :years_in_current_industry, :hobbies

end
```

message.rb

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sender, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :recipient, class_name: "User"

  validates :content, presence: true, length: { maximum: 500 }
  validates :sender_id, presence: true
  validates :recipient_id, presence: true
end
```

messages/index.html.erb

```
<h2>Inbox</h2>
```

messages/new.html.erb

```
<h1>Create Message</h1>

<%= form_for [@recipient, @message] do |f| %>

    <%= f.hidden_field :recipient_id, value: @recipient.id %>

    <%= f.label "Enter your message below" %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :content %>

    <%= f.submit "Send" %>
<% end %>
```

rake routes

```
user_messages POST   /users/:user_id/messages(.:format)     messages#create
    new_user_message GET    /users/:user_id/messages/new(.:format) messages#new
               users GET    /users(.:format)                       users#index
                     POST   /users(.:format)                       users#create
            new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                   users#new
           edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)              users#edit
                user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                   users#show
                     PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)                   users#update
                     PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                   users#update
                     DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                   users#destroy
            messages GET    /messages(.:format)                    messages#index
             message GET    /messages/:id(.:format)                messages#show
                     DELETE /messages/:id(.:format)                messages#destroy
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Models**

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :messages, class_name: "Message", foreign_key: "recipient_id"
   has_many :sent_messages, class_name: "Message", foreign_key: "sender_id"
end

#app/models/message.rb
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :recipient, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "recipient_id"
   belongs_to :sender, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "sender_id"
   scope :unread, -> { where read: false }
end
```

This should give you the ability to create messages which "belong" to a user (IE the recipient), and then you can associate a "sender" profile to those messages.

--

**Controllers**

This will give you the ability to call the following:

```
#app/controllers/messages_controller.rb
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
   before_action :set_recipient, only: [:new, :create]

   def new
      @message = current_user.sent_messages.new
   end

   def create
      @message = current_user.sent_messages.new message_params
      @message.recipient_id = @recipient.id
      @message.save
   end

   def index
      @messages = current_user.messages
   end

   def destroy
      @message = current_user.messages.destroy params[:id]
   end

   def show
      @message = current_user.messages.find params[:id]
   end

   private

   def message_params
      params.require(:message).permit(:content, :recipient_id, :sender_id)
   end

   def set_recipient
       @recipient = User.find params[:user_id]
   end
end
```

--

**Routes**

```
#config/routes.rb
devise_for :users, path: "", controllers: { :registrations => "registrations" }, path_names: {sign_up: "register", sign_in: "login", sign_out: "logout"}

resources :users do
   get :profile
   resources :messages, only: [:new, :create] #-> domain.com/users/:user_id/messages/new
end
resources :messages, only: [:index, :show, :destroy] #-> domain.com/messages/:id
```

--

**Views**

This will give you the ability to use the following links:

```
#app/views/users/show.html.erb (user to send message to)
<%= link_to "Send Message", user_messages_path(@user.id) %>

#app/views/messages/new.html.erb
<%= form_for [@recipient, @user] do |f| %>
     <%= f.text_field :content %>
     <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>

#app/views/messages/index.html.erb
<h2>Inbox</h2>
<% @messages.each do |message| %>
   <%= message.content %>
<% end %>
```

--

**Fix**

> I've read that the thing to do is add the User_id field to the table,
>   but I'm hoping to link this messages up using sender_id and
>   recipient_id, which both equal user_id (e.g. User 1[sender] sends a
>   message to User 2 [recipient])

You **don't** need to add `user_id` to your table. `user_id` is merely a [`foreign_key`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key), which you've overridden in your `models`.

All you need to do is set the `recipient_id` and `sender_id`, which we're doing in the `create` method:

```
def create
   @message = current_user.message.new message_params
   @message.recipient_id = @recipient.id
   @message.save
end
```

You've done some very clever things here.

Firstly, you have implicitly set the `sender_id` foreign key by calling `current_user.messages`. If you had called `Message.new`, it would have been a completely different story (having to set `sender_id`)

Secondly, because you're using nested routes, you'll be able to use the `@recipient` variable you've set in the `before_action` method to give us the `id` for the `recipient_id`.

This should work for you. You won't need to use `inverse_of` unless you are trying to access "parent" model data in a child / nested model.

---

**Recommendations**

What you're doing is completely valid

The core trick is to make sure your `Message` model is completely separate & independent to your `User`. This is achieved with your setup, allowing you to create the various objects that you require.

The other aspect you need to consider is how you're going to ensure you're able to provide the users with the ability to have ["threaded" messages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversation_threading). You'll achieve this using one of the hierarchy gems, either [`Ancestry`](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry) or [`Closure_Tree`](https://github.com/mceachen/closure_tree)

Adding this functionality will be a little more in-depth. I can provide information if you require (just leave a comment)

---

**Threading**

The hierarchy gems are actually relatively simple to use.

The trick to "treading" your messages is to use one of these gems (either `Ancestry` or `Closure_Tree`), as they provide you with "methods" which you can call on your items. They work by creating several columns in your database, populating them as you save / create the objects you desire

The "threading" issue is a big one, as without the "hierarchy" gems, you won't be able to call the "child" objects of the record you want, thus preventing the threading from occurring. Here's a [good Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/262-trees-with-ancestry) on how to achieve it:

[image]

The trick with this is to use something called ["recursion"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion)

Recursion is where you create an "indefinite" loop, so far as how "recursive" the data is. EG if you have an object with children, you'll have to cycle through the children, and then the children of those children, *recursively* until you reach the point of showing all the data:

> Recursion is the process of repeating items in a self-similar way. For
>   instance, when the surfaces of two mirrors are exactly parallel with
>   each other, the nested images that occur are a form of infinite
>   recursion.

As such, here's how you to it:

> 1. Make sure you save your objects with the correct parents
> 2. To display the "threaded" conversation, loop through those parents
> 3. Use recursion to loop through their children

We use the [`ancestry`](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry) gem, which stores the hierarchy slightly differently to the `closure_tree` gem we've since discovered (intend to use the closure tree gem soon).

You firstly have to therefore save any hierarchy yourself:

[image]

This will allow you to save the various "parents" for that object. This means that when you load the object, and wish to cycle through its descendent, you'll be able to use the [Ancestry object methods](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry#navigating-your-tree):

[image]

Which means you'll be able to use the following:

```
#app/views/comments/index.html.erb
<%= render partial: "comments", locals: { collection: @comments } %>

#app/comments/_comments.html.erb
<% collection.arrange.each do |comment, sub_item| %>
    <%= link_to comment.title, comment_path(comment) %>

    <% if category.has_children? %>
        <%= render partial: "category", locals: { collection: category.children } %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Rich, thanks for the quick reply. I would really like some more information on hierarchy gems, but don't want to waste your time if you think I can find the info online. Separately, I'm having trouble with routes right now, with the following error: No route matches [POST] "/messages". I've added my rake routes above. Do you think that the issue here is that I have messages as a nested resource as well as a standalone? Thanks!

Comment: Rich, apologies for the gap in between questions, but I'm getting ready to build the reply function of this messaging system. Do I need to have the framework for replying to a message without threading before I can incorporate the Hierarchy gem? or does the order not matter.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the error you have, try to set `:inverse_of` attribute of `has_many` and `belongs_to` statements in your model classes. You can end up having two `has_many` - one per each `belongs_to` reverse:

```
user.rb:
has_many :from_messages, :class_name => 'Message', :foreign_key => "sender_id",     :inverse_of => :sender
has_many :to_messages, :class_name => 'Message', :foreign_key => "to_id", :inverse_of => :recipient

message.rb:
belongs_to :sender, :class_name => 'User', :inverse_of => :from_messages
belongs_to :recipient, :class_name => 'User',:inverse_of => :to_messages
```

Overall I think your approach is a good starting point for a messaging system. You can try to post your code to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for a detailed review.

Comment: Roman, thanks for the quick response. This is the first that I'm hearing of :inverse_of, but I will read up on it. Additionally, made some headway, on the project, can now display the message form, but it all breaks down after hitting submit. I'll look into the changes that you suggested, but for now, updated code above. Thanks again!