# Post message to multiple groups Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, data-modeling

First time question asker here... New to Rails and data modeling in general.

The closest I've come to an answer can be found [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25752438/rails-user-to-user-messages), however, I'm having difficulty translating this to the flow of the app I'm working on.

The general flow is this:

1. User can create one or multiple groups
2. Groups can have other users as "members". Members can view all messages in a group.
3. User can create a new message and have it post to one or more of User's own groups (minimum requirement is that at least one group is selected)
4. Group members can view the message that was posted.

The question I have is specific to User posting a Message to a Group.

Based on the above-referenced link, here's how I am modeling the ActiveRecords

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :groups
   has_many :sent_messages, class_name: "Message", foreign_key: "sender_id"
end

#app/models/message.rb
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :recipient, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "recipient_id"
   belongs_to :sender, class_name: "Group", foreign_key: "sender_id"
end

#app/models/group.rb
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   has_many :messages, class_name "Message", foreign_key: "recipient_id"
end
```

My question is, generally is this the right approach? I realize (I think) that it is best practice to separate general flow types (e.g., creating groups, sending messages, managing group members, etc.)... But is it okay to bifurcate the foreign keys in the Message models so that they're pointing one to User and the other to Group?

Comment: I think this approach is sane and I can't see anything wrong with it.  It's a normalized design and straight forward

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, Ilan! I tested it out and it's all working well now.