# Rails messaging

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I m create a messaging between users.
Take info from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25752438/rails-user-to-user-messages?rq=1).

But then I go for new message, I have a error.

```
NoMethodError in MessagesController#new
undefined method `relation_delegate_class' for "Message":String

  def new
    @message = current_user.sent_messages.new
  end
```

How can I fix it?
Thanks.

Message model:

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sender, :class_name=>'User', foreign_key: 'sender_id'
  belongs_to :recipient, :class_name=>'User', foreign_key: 'receiver_id'
end
```

User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sent_messages, class: 'Message', foreign_key: 'sender_id'
  has_many :messages, class: 'Message', foreign_key: 'receiver_id' 
end
```

Message controller:

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController

def new
  @message = current_user.sent_messages.new
end

def create
  @message = current_user.messages.new message_params
  @message.receiver_id = @recipient.id
  @message.save
end

private

def message_params
  params.require(:message).permit(:text, :receiver_id, :sender_id)
end

def set_recipient
 @recipient = User.find(params[:id])
end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `class` attribute on associations you should specify **actual class**, a constant like `Message`. You could use `"Message"` too, but only in `class_name`.

In fact, what the message says is "you're doing something unexpected with a String", the solution is to look what strings you may have in the wrong places.

Comment: Also you might want to change `@message = current_user.sent_messages.new` to a more readable `@message = Message.new(sender: current_user)`. Doing the other way reads like the message is already sent.

Comment: @papirtiger I advise against it, since it delves into the lower-level details of the association and should its parameters change this could stop working. It's just a minor naming problem and it is easily handled by the contextual meaning of the model.